# Best way to backup my whole app (sqlite, folders and files) - Android

Tags: android, backup

I have an app that creates some folders and loads lots of images inside of them. These images are also registered inside the app database.

So far, so good. These days I had to format my tablet due to a huge problem. I lost all images and also all the database.

Is there a way to backup (and restore) all this? It could be done locally or stored in my website folder or ftp.

I saw some Android's backup classes but it seems they don't do what I want (backup files, folders and database) and I have to register to Google's own backup service.

Can anyone help me, please?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use this [cloud storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/). It's the only thing that makes sense in your case.